# Not trying to use /Common endpoint, but Azure AD believes I am

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm using my organization's Azure AD to authenticate users on a corporate web app. I intend for this to be a single-tenant application. When I run it, I'm prompted to log in with my organization's credentials, as expected. On submitting my credentials, however, I get this error:

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS50194: Application '*appId*'(*appname*) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

The thing is, *I'm not trying to use the /common endpoint.* Here is the relevant bit of my appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "COMPANYDOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "MYTENANTID-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
"ClientId": "MYCLIENTID-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

And here's the app's settings in the Azure portal (Home>AppRegistrations>App>PlatformConfigurations>Authentication):
[image: The app's Supported Account Types setting with 'Accounts in this organizational directory only' selected.]

My startup.cs, which I assumed set the endpoint in question, is taken directly from the Microsoft-provided sample:

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    });
```

I've also set `false` to `true` for kicks, but the result was the same.

What am I doing wrong, here? Why does Azure AD continue to believe I want to use the /common endpoint?

---

Edit: As I continued to search, I happened on @jack-jia's answer here: [Application is not configured as a multi-tenant application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864036/application-is-not-configured-as-a-multi-tenant-application)

I haven't quite solved my issue, but their answer offered some promising clues.

Comment: Try use fiddler or postman to trace the AAD authentication request . Check whether `common` is include rather than your tenant id/name

Comment: Also double check the Authority in your options under a debugger. If that doesn't solve it, then it could be it's not being overridden correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have configured it as single tenant application on Azure portal, this issue must occurred due to the wrong authorization endpoint. Please check the value of **options.Authority** again. If it is identified as single tenant, you can use fiddler to capture the request, the request is something like

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Check if the endpoint is correct.

Comment: You're right -- while I was sure my endpoint was set correctly, I completely failed to consider the Angular front end I had, and the fact that environment.ts became the source of the Azure authority, not appsettings.json. Such a dumb mistake on my part, but a good reminder to consider anywhere I might have set the "Authority" property.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same error but using python to authenticate my API calls.

Specifically I was using authOAuthDesktopMobileAuthCodeGrant class from bingads.authorization

The solution I ended up with is as follows:

The **init** for authOAuthDesktopMobileAuthCodeGrant shows the following, note that tenant is defaulted to "common".

```
def __init__(self, client_id, oauth_tokens=None, env=PRODUCTION, oauth_scope=MSADS_MANAGE, **tenant='common'**):
```

Therefore, in order to overwrite /common like others here have done. I had to set this tenant component here to my app's tenant ID

```
authentication = OAuthDesktopMobileAuthCodeGrant(
        client_id=client_id,
        tenant="{YOUR_TENANT_ID}",
        env='production'
```

Hope this is useful to others who are working out of python.